# Dry red patches on face?

Tags: face, menstruation, rash, eczema, dry-skin

Around two or three days ago I noticed some unusual dry red patches started forming on my face. They're dry, rather itchy, and red even though some aren't that red. As of now, I have them under my eyes near my cheekbones, the sides of my face and the area around my jaw. At first I assume this happens because I'm near my menstrual cycle (I'm currently seventeen years old), however this never happens before. I tried Googling and the symptoms are most similar to eczema, but I'm not that sure. I've been layering on moisturizer to soothe it but nothing happens. What am I supposed to do to heal/reduce these dry patches and what causes it? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Health SE. I understand that you are trying to learn about what could be causing this, but policy prohibits seeking medical advice on this site.  Part of why is that it could cause harm to give you advice in any setting other than an exam by a clinician.  Skin is especially tricky.  That could be anything from a reaction to a lotion or something like a malar rash in lupus.  No way for anyone here to know - see your doctor for evaluation.